# Split a 'Decimal' in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, split, decimal

I am sure this is a very simple problem, but I am new to VB.NET, so I am having an issue with it.

I have a `Decimal` variable, and I need to split it into two separate variables, one containing the integer part, and one containing the fractional part.

For example, for x = 12.34 you would end up with a y = 12 and a z = 0.34.

Is there a nice built-in functions to do this or do I have to try and work it out manually?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [Math.Truncate(decimal)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d101hyf.aspx) and then subtract that from the original. Be aware that that will give you a negative value for both parts if the input is decimal (e.g. -1.5 => -1, -.5)

EDIT: Here's a version of Eduardo's code which uses decimal throughout:

```
Sub SplitDecimal(ByVal number As Decimal, ByRef wholePart As Decimal, _
                 ByRef fractionalPart As Decimal)
    wholePart = Math.Truncate(number)
    fractionalPart = number - wholePart
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

(As Jon Skeet says), beware that the integer part of a decimal can be greater than an integer, but this function will get you the idea.

```
    Sub SlipDecimal(ByVal Number As Decimal, ByRef IntegerPart As Integer, _
                    ByRef DecimalPart As Decimal)
        IntegerPart = Int(Number)
        DecimalPart = Number - IntegerPart
    End Sub
```

Use the Jon version if you are using big numbers.

Comment: Decimals can go way outside the range of Integers (and Longs)

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
DecimalNumber - Int(DecimalNumber)
```

Comment: I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only or link-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: This solution only works for positive numbers. It should be DecimalNumber -Int(Math.Truncate(DecimalNumber))

Answer (score 1):

Fractional and decimal part of a number have different significance when a number is above zero or below zero. Therefore, you have to consider both cases.
I suggest using the below code:

```
Dim dbl as double = 13.067
Dim int1 As Integer = 0
Dim fraction As Double = 0
If dbl >= 0 Then
    int1 = Math.Floor(dbl)
ElseIf dbl < 0 Then
    int1 = Math.Ceiling(dbl)
End If
fraction = dbl - int1
```

fraction holdes 0.067, and int1 holds 13 .
Floor and Ceiling, round any fractional number to the lowest, and highest consecutive integer, respectively.