# Fractional Part of Doubles without using string manipulation

Tags: vb.net, double

Is there a way to get the fraction parts of a Double without using string manipulations? Specifically in vb.net?

There are numerous examples for a decimal in various languages. [One for vb.net is this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362441/split-a-decimal-in-vb-net)

Basically they all seem to use either a mod or Truncate method or they take advantage of casting to integer behavior. But none of those approaches will work for a double/float type due to the inherent inaccuracy of the double/float type. There is also the problem that doubles don't cast to decimals reliably. Below is a test case to show what I mean and expect.

```
<TestClass> _
    Public Class BasicNumberTests

        Function DecimalFractionalPart(ByVal number As Decimal) As Decimal
            Dim wholePart As Decimal = Math.Truncate(number)
            Return number - wholePart
        End Function

        Function DoubleFractionalPart(ByVal number As Double) As Double
            Dim wholePart As Double = Math.Truncate(number)
            Return number - wholePart
        End Function

        <TestMethod()> Public Sub SplitDoubleAsDecimal1()
            Dim number As Double = 0.65 + 0.05
            Dim fractionalPart As Double = CDbl(DecimalFractionalPart(CDec(number)))
            Assert.AreEqual(0.70000000000000007, number)
            Assert.AreEqual(0.70000000000000007, fractionalPart) '<- Fails
        End Sub

        <TestMethod()> Public Sub SplitDoubleAsDecimal2()
            Dim number As Double = 0.70000000000000007
            Dim fractionalPart As Double = CDbl(DecimalFractionalPart(CDec(number)))

            Assert.AreEqual(0.70000000000000007, number)
            Assert.AreEqual(0.70000000000000007, fractionalPart) '<- Fails
        End Sub

        <TestMethod()> Public Sub SplitDoubleAsDouble1()
            Dim number As Double = 1.65

            Assert.AreEqual(1.65, number)
            Assert.AreEqual(0.65, DoubleFractionalPart(number)) '<- Fails
        End Sub

        <TestMethod()> Public Sub SplitDoubleAsDouble2()
            Dim number As Double = 1.0 + 0.65
            Assert.AreEqual(1.65, number)
            Assert.AreEqual(0.65, DoubleFractionalPart(number)) '<- Fails
        End Sub

End Class
```

To get around this I have methods that use string manipulation to get the fractional part. The problem with this is that it only works with certain formatting types.

I asked this question (incorrectly) in another place and (before my question was deleted) some person said it *would* work with doubles which I didn't understand.

(To be clear I do realize that the Double you see isn't always exactly the actual number it appears to be. I know that .65 + .05 <> .7  But I also know that 0.70000000000000007 is always = 0.70000000000000007 = .65 + .05 and so on. But I want the fractional part of the decimal AS IT APPEARS TO BE.)

Am I missing something? Is there a way to get the fractional part of doubles reliably without using string manipulation?

If I must use string manipulation how can I do this so that it will always work regardless of the cultural formatting?

EDIT-The tests show what I want. If the Double is 0.70000000000000007 I want the method to return 0.70000000000000007.  If it is .65 I want .65 returned.  Since .65 + .05 = 0.70000000000000007 then GetFractionalParts(.65 + .05) should return 0.70000000000000007

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
REM Add: Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

<Extension()>
Public Function getFractionalPart(ByVal number As Single) As Single
    Return number - Math.Truncate(number)
End Function

<Extension()>
Public Function getFractionalPart(ByVal number As Double) As Double
    Return number - Math.Truncate(number)
End Function

<Extension()>
Public Function getFractionalPart(ByVal number As Decimal) As Decimal
    Return number - Math.Truncate(number)
End Function
```

## Gotcha

Note however, that:

```
    Dim number As Double = 10 * 0.69
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(6.9D))
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(number))
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(6.9D.getFractionalPart()))
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(number.getFractionalPart()))
```

Will print out:

```
    4619454727784602010
    4619454727784602009
    4606281698874543309
    4606281698874543304
```

Reason for this is, that `10 * 0.69` is not same as `6.9`, this is because `double` is an approximated value. Note also that `10 * 0.69` and `6.9` differed only by 1 mantissa increment. Reason why their fractional part differs more then 1 mantissa increment, is IEEE 754 - increment is not constant. Values near 0 are more accurate and this is 'not a bug, but a feature', as thy are most common.

I'm not sure what you want to fix.

If you want to print out `correct` value, then you can use Jon Skeet's method `ToExactString`:
http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs

Comment: That is basically what everybody else was doing for decimals.