# Use regular expression to split up a decimal number

Tags: c#

Using VS 2012, Windows Forms, C#

If I have a `decimal` variable called `productPrice` and I want to split it up into two numbers, the number to the left of the decimal, and the decimal and the number to the right, what is the `regex` pattern I need to use?

For example: if `productPrice = 3.75` how can i split it up so i have one variable that is `3`, and one variable that is `.75`

Thanks!

Comment: Did you know that on a German system, it is not a dot (`.`) but a comma (`,`) being used as the decimal separator?

Comment: Of course [the best answer comes from Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/362453/107625). Plus, you don't have to unnecessarily convert to strings.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have a decimal type, you can cast to an integer to get the integer part:

```
var intPortion = (int)productPrice;
var remainder = productPrice - intPortion;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex to do this you can do a simple `productPrice.ToString().Split('.')`

to use this numbers you can do

```
var price = productPrice.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB")).Split('.');
var dolars = price[0];
var cents = price[1];
```

Comment: Would not work here in Germany, though ;-)

Comment: How do I then use those numbers though? And I need to keep the decimal for the second number, I am trying to split an amount of money into the dollars and cents of the total.

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby You could use something like `productPrice.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Split('.')`.

Comment: @UweKeim Here in brasil too lol ! but if he did `productPrice.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB")).Split('.')`

Comment: -1 for going through a string representation.